# How to split array into different repeating chunks of m and n size

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of 40 numbers and I need to create from it a new array of n and m chunks length:

```
const arr = [1..40];
```

after working out the algorithm I need, I get results like the following:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [9,10], [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18], [19,20], ...]
```

I'm trying to use this example but it splits onto same sizes chunks

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var myArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
        myArray.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update the question with the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach with an array of the chunk sizes.

```js
var values = Array.from({ length: 40 }, (_, i) => i + 1),
    chunks = [8, 2],
    indexC = 0,
    indexV = 0,
    result = [];
    
while (indexV < values.length) {
    result.push(values.slice(indexV, indexV += chunks[indexC]));
    indexC++;
    indexC %= chunks.length;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58706995/2668568) is very elegant. Here's a somewhat convoluted alternative using generators and iterators:

```js
function buildNestedChunksArray(maxNum, chunkDefArr) {
  var mySetValues = new Set(Object.keys(Array.from({
      length: maxNum
    }))).values(),
    i = 0,
    z = 0,
    result = [];
  var chunkGenerators = chunkDefArr.map(chunkSize => {
    return function*() {
      var index = 0;
      while (index < chunkSize) {
        yield mySetValues.next().value;
        index++;
      }

    }
  })
  while (i < maxNum) {
    var chunkGen = chunkGenerators[z](),
      chunkVals = [];
    while (next = chunkGen.next(), !next.done) {
      chunkVals.push(parseInt(next.value, 10) + 1);
      i++;
    }
    z++, z %= chunkGenerators.length;
    result.push(chunkVals);
  }
  console.log(result);
}

buildNestedChunksArray(42, [6, 4, 2]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```